# How do I restart the seeds.rb columns from zero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails, how can i get the seeds.rb to restart counting from 0 every single time?

Currently when i re-run: rake db:seed, the autoincrement columns keep increasing higher and higher.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rails, auto-incrementing is handled in the database, thus I ask: what database are you using?

Comment: @andrew-marshall: I am actually using sqlite on my local and will be using mysql on dev and prod environment, is there something that works universally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you can use this

```
table_name = 'xyz'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name}")
```

before seeding values in seed.rb

Comment: I am actually using sqlite on my local and will be using mysql on dev and prod environment, is there something that works universally?